# Remove payload from spring integration logs in debug level

Tags: logging, spring-integration

I'm using **spring integration** in my application,
The information in the **payload** of messages are **sensitive** so I don't want it to be logged.
I've removed all of the payloads from spring integration INFO logs but,
when changing spring integration log level to **DEBUG**,
the payload and headers of messages are logged when 
messages are sent on various components of spring integration.

The question is how could I disable logging of payload of message in DEBUG mode?
(Is there any way to **extend** logging facility of spring integration and introduce my own implementation to spring integration?)
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a custom Appender (implementation depending on what logging subsystem you use). Or, you use a patched version of Apache Commons Logging to remove the payload in the logger before it gets to the appender).